# How do I proceed when I can't access a company's online paperwork for my job application?

Tags: communication, job-search, new-job

My significant other has finished interviewing for a job and it looks like she's likely to get an offer. The company is asking her to complete some online forms, including one of those personality assessment quizzes, before sending her the offer.

Unfortunately, the website just isn't working for her. She's tried accessing it from multiple different browsers on multiple different computers, but the website doesn't work on any of them. I'm a developer and I helped her look at it, but it really does look like the website is just not rendering correctly; another developer friend of ours came to the same conclusion. This means that unfortunately, she just can't complete the paperwork.

She's emailed the company's HR representative asking for help. Is there anything else she should do in this situation?

Comment: "Is there anything else she should do?" -- yes, call the HR (or any other future employer contact she might have) on the phone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> *She's emailed the company's HR representative asking for help. Is there anything else she should do in this situation?*

You did *almost* everything that needs to be done, just to make sure the information is not missed / lost, call them up (the HR, Recruiter or the contact person - as applicable) and inform about the issue.